# Nginx redirects to ```https://server_name/ ```URL instead of ```https://server_name/projectname/``` , after changing the URL from http to https

Tags: nginx, redirect, django

I have a couple of URLs like `https://server_name/projectname/`, now the problem is if I type this URL on the browser, Django (or Nginx) redirects me to `https://server_name/`, which does not exist. Actually, it should redirect me to `https://server_name/projectname/`.
Now the question is how can I say Django (or Nginx ) to do this, I don't really know if the problem is in Django or in Nginx config. I Have tried FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME= '/projectname' in settings.py but it didn't help for all urls for example `https://server_name/projectname/admin`.
By the way, it was working very well before changing the HTTP to HTTPs.

Nginx config in sites-available/project_name

```
upstream project_name_app{
  server unix:/home/webapps/project_name/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}


server {

    listen 127.0.0.1:100;
    server_name servername;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1600;

    proxy_connect_timeout       1600;
    proxy_send_timeout          1600;
    proxy_read_timeout          1600;
    send_timeout                1600;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/webapps/projectname/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/webapps/projectname/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /home/webapps/projectname/project_name/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /home/webapps/projectname/project_name/media/;
    }

    location /{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://project_name_app;
            break;

        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /home/webapps/projectname/project_name/templates/;
    }
}
```

Nginx reverse proxy config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name servername;

        # https redirect
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate ...;
        ssl_certificate_key ...;

        root /home/webapps/landing/landing;
        index index.html;

        # Improve HTTPS performance with session resumption
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;

        # Enable server-side protection against BEAST attacks
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "ddfdf";

        # RFC-7919 recommended: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#ffdhe4096
        ssl_dhparam /;
        ssl_ecdh_curve /;

        
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

        # ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
        # add_header X-Frame-Options DENY always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

        # ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;

        # ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection
        add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

        # Reverse Proxy
        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf;
}
```

And included proxy reverse in the last line:

```
location /projectname/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

        proxy_read_timeout 1000;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1000;
        proxy_send_timeout 1000;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:100/;
        sub_filter '="/' '="/projectname/';

        sub_filter_once off;
}
```

Main URL in Django

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('dashboards/', include('dashboards.urls')),
    path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
    re_path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
]
```

pages url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index-pages'),
    re_path(r'^login/$', views.login_page, name='login'),
    re_path(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]
```

dashboard url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django supports SCRIPT_NAME just fine. Whether its enforced in configuration, sent by the WSGI server or passed through from any reverse proxy, it will work on its own. Jumping through hoops just to hide the path prefix from an application is only needed or desirable when working with software *not* supporting being rooted in a subfolder.

Configure `MEDIA_URL` & `STATIC_URL` and remove the `sub_filter`/`sub_filter_once` lines and the trailing slash in `proxy_pass` from your nginx configuration.
That will **send the path *including* the prefix** over to gunicorn, and Django will be able to handle it.

---

I would also highly recommend eliminating the double proxy. The configuration regarding the application could be inlined right into the `location /projectname/ {}` name in the https server block, instead of establishing *another* potential source for difficult-to-diagnose HTTP proxying peculiarities/bugs/vulnerabilities.

Comment: thank your very much, man you saved my time